# C++ Homework Doesn't Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, char

So, I'm super new to C++ and am sharing a book with a friend. I'm creating a simple guessing game, where the user imagines a number, and the computer attempts to guess it. When I debug in Visual Studio, the project does make a guess, and properly prints "how did I do?". At this point, it should get user input for the 'feedback' variable. After the prompt, however, it seems as if it will only repeat everything before the 'while' statement. Does the problem concern the feedback char variable (maybe I should've just used 'cin' and integers?), or am I just missing something really obvious?

```
//Game that attempts to guess a number from one to twenty.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
auto lowbound = 1;
auto highbound = 20;
auto guess = 10;
auto gamecont = true;

char feedback[1];


cout << " Pick a number from one to twenty in you head and I'll guess it; no cheating!" << endl << endl;
cout << " If my guess is too low, just say (1). If too high, say (2). Say (3) if I've got it. It's (ENTER) to get going!" << endl << endl;
cout << " Waiting on you..." << endl << " ";

cin.get();

while(gamecont)
{

    cout << " I'm thinking your number is " << guess << "." << endl << endl;
    cout << " How did I do?" << endl << endl << " ";

    cin.get(feedback, 1);

    if (feedback[1] == 1) // The guess was too low.
    {
        if (guess == 10)
        {
            guess = 15;
        }
        else if (guess >= 15)
        {
            guess++;
        }
        else if (guess < 10)
        {
            guess++;
        }
    }
    else if (feedback[1] == 2) // The guess was too high.
    {
        if (guess == 10)
        {
            guess = 5;
        }
        else if (guess <= 5)
        {
            guess--;
        }
        else if (guess > 10)
        {
            guess--;
        }
    }
    else if (feedback[1] == 3) // The guess was correct.
    {
        gamecont = false;
    }


}

return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this question is stupid for whatever reason, and thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are zero based. And "maybe I should've just used 'cin' and integers?" - yes.

Comment: char '1' and integer 1 are different things

Comment: BTW, a single character variable may be easier to work with than a array of 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step, so here´s some aid for your first step:

```
using namespace std;
```

don´t do that. `std::` is crowded with identifiers you might use too, problems are guaranteed.

```
char feedback[1];
```

You´ll never have input longer than 1, so

```
char feedback;
```

is more than appropriate. (besides: arrays are 0 based so it should have been `char feedback[0];` instead of `char feedback[1];`)

```
cout << " Pick a number from one to twenty in you head and I'll guess it; no cheating!" << endl << endl;
```

`std::endl` flushes the buffer, no need to do that twice. Simply use `'\n'`:

```
std::cout << " Pick a number from one to twenty in you head and I'll guess it; no cheating!" << "\n\n";
```

you´ll get the character code of the key in `feedback`. `'1'` is not equal to `1`, so

```
if (feedback == 1)
```

should be

```
if (feedback == '1')
```

Thats it. There still some work remaining to do for you, e.g. the guessing strategy is poor, but that should be a start.

```
//Game that attempts to guess a number from one to twenty.

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto lowbound = 1;
    auto highbound = 20;
    auto guess = 10;
    auto gamecont = true;

    char feedback;


    std::cout << " Pick a number from one to twenty in you head and I'll guess it; no cheating!" << "\n\n";
    std::cout << " If my guess is too low, just say (1). If too high, say (2). Say (3) if I've got it. It's (ENTER) to get going!" << "\n\n";
    std::cout << " Waiting on you..." << "\n\n";

    std::cin.get();

    while(gamecont)
    {

        std::cout << " I'm thinking your number is " << guess << "." << "\n\n";
        std::cout << " How did I do?" << "\n\n";

        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.get(feedback);

        if (feedback == '1') // The guess was too low.
        {
            if (guess == 10)
            {
                guess = 15;
            }
            else if (guess >= 15)
            {
                guess++;
            }
            else if (guess < 10)
            {
                guess++;
            }
        }
        else if (feedback == '2') // The guess was too high.
        {
            if (guess == 10)
            {
                guess = 5;
            }
            else if (guess <= 5)
            {
                guess--;
            }
            else if (guess > 10)
            {
                guess--;
            }
        }
        else if (feedback == '3') // The guess was correct.
        {
            gamecont = false;
        }



    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: generally awesome advice, and I appreciate you. It took me a while to get even this to work, because "I'm thinking your number is" would repeat and `int guess` would remain ten. After implementing everything else (and turning off precompiled headers in VS2017), I discovered that simply switching the places of `std::cin.ignore();` and `std::cin.get(feedback);` caused everything to work properly. `\n` is the bomb, btw. The only thing I still don't get is when you mention that arrays are 0-based, so it must be written differently anyway. I can't tell the difference between them :(. TY

Comment: great that it was of help. Indeed I didn´t paste the right code I forgot to change the if (feedback == 1) etc to if (feedback == '1'), the explanation was right but the code was wrong, sorry!    The zero-based thing isn´t important any more since the arrays are removed but if you have an array it should have been char feedback[0]; and not char feedback[1];. (Yep, sorry type in my answer. Both typos are fixed. Thank you for pointing that out!